# Chrome extension icon not appearing

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension

```
    [!["manifest_version": 2,
    "icons": {
        "16": "/images/icon16.png",
        "48": "/images/icon48.png",
        "128": "/images/icon128.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {                    
            "16": "images/icon16.png",          
            "48": "images/icon48.png",
            "128": "images/icon128.png"       
          },
        "default_popup": "/screens/popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": \["tabs", "storage", "webNavigation"\],
    "content_scripts": \[
        {
            "js": \["popup.js", "websites.js"\],
            "matches": \[
                "<all_urls>"
            \]
        }
    \],
    "background": {
        "scripts": \["background.js"\],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com; object-src 'self';"
}
```

[image: it is giving me the blue puzzle piece in the middle]

I don't know why my chrome extension icon isn't showing. I saved all the icons into the images folder hence the /images. it is giving me the blue puzzle piece in the middle Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you forget to add "/" at browser_actions icons? Can you try like this "/images/icon16.png"

Comment: I still have the same problem after adding the "/"

Comment: Chrome puts new extensions inside the puzzle menu. You're yet another victim of its developers' refusal to listen to users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example is working on my browser. I don't know why your manifest json starts with [![. Maybe this is the problem. I'm not sure. Can you edit this example according to your json file?

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test",
  "description": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/icon16.png",
      "48": "images/icon48.png",
      "128": "images/icon128.png"
    },
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

Comment: mine still isn't working. I guess it could be a problem with the images.

Answer (score 0):

Try copy-pasting this into your manifest.json file. You have loads of artefacts that might cause issues, I also removed the default_icons key which isn't necessary in my opinion. Also removed the backslash / before the image folder-paths.

```
{
  "name": "Some extension",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon16.png",
    "48": "images/icon48.png",
    "128": "images/icon128.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "/screens/popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs", "storage", "webNavigation"],
  "content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["popup.js", "websites.js"],
    "matches": [
      "<all_urls>"
    ]
  }],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com; object-src 'self';"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues. I opened the png file(s) with paint and resaved them and it worked. So please verify your png files.